# How to block a code in specific file in developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

When loading the index.html page in the index file there is javascript code. How can I block this particular code when the page index.html is loading?

the code that I want to block is

```
<script>
    (function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            dataLayer.push({
            'a': '13'            
            });        
        }, 100);
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using developer tools(three-dot menu > More Tools > Developer Tools), you can delete lines in the website for the ongoing session. This would effectively prevent the script from running. If you want to see all the scripts on the sites you visit, use the [Firefox browser](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) coupled with the NoScript add-on. This will show you all the scripts on the site, and allow you to give various permissions to each of them. If you own the index.html file and have it on your local computer, then simply comment out or delete the script that you don't want.

Comment: the file index.html does not belong to me. 
Ok but using developer tools how can I delete line in the file before the file is loaded?

Comment: You can't delete the line in a remote file before it is loaded. You can delete the script before it starts running, and that would effectively prevent it from running for that one time. If the file does not belong to you, you can't make changes to it and you shouldn't even try to. That kind of procedure could get you in trouble.